# Which Unicode table does the value of primitive type char refer to in java?

Tags: java

I want to find code table for the value of primitive type `char` in java, and I heard that java uses Unicode internally. Which Unicode table does the value of primitive type `char` refer to in java?

Comment: [`Character literals can only represent UTF-16 code units (§3.1), i.e., they are limited to values from \u0000 to \uffff.`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in [the Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html):

> When the specification for the Java language was created, the Unicode
> standard was accepted and the char primitive was defined as a 16-bit
> data type, with characters in the hexadecimal range from 0x0000 to
> 0xFFFF.
>
> Because 16-bit encoding supports 216 (65,536) characters, which is insufficient to define all characters in use throughout the world,
> the Unicode standard was extended to 0x10FFFF, which supports over one
> million characters. The definition of a character in the Java
> programming language could not be changed from 16 bits to 32 bits
> without causing millions of Java applications to no longer run
> properly. To correct the definition, a scheme was developed to handle
> characters that could not be encoded in 16 bits.
>
> The characters with values that are outside of the 16-bit range, and within the range from 0x10000 to 0x10FFFF, are called
> supplementary characters and are defined as a pair of char values.

Check the unicode character table [here](http://unicode-table.com/en/).

Answer (score 1):

Java uses [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) strings. Each char is a 16-bit code *unit* in the UTF-16 scheme. For code *points* in the basic multilingual plane (U+0000 to U+FFFF) the values are identical. Part of this range is reserved for surrogate pairs which allow UTF-16 to represent values above the BMP.

To get the [chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) code point value for any char you can use one of the code point methods:

```
public class PrintCodePoints {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "e\u0301\uD835\uDD0A\u20AC";
    for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
      int codePoint = test.codePointAt(i);
      if (codePoint > 0xFFFF) {
        i++;
      }
      System.out.format("U+%04x%n", codePoint);
    }
  }
}
```

This code prints the code point values for the literal string "é𝔊€".